# Akka Scheduler Inaccuracy

Tags: akka

I need to send a regular message to an actor at a fairly high fixed rate - approx 30Hz to 120Hz. I'm currently using Akka's built in scheduler but I have found that it is pretty inaccurate. It's out by 10's of milliseconds and fluctuates a lot.

I tried to increase the schedulers accuracy by reducing the tick-duration and ticks-per-wheel but I can't reduce the tick-duration below 10ms and changing the ticks-per-wheel had no effect.

My solution for now is to create a simple Java thread that sends a message to the actor after sleeping for a fixed amount of time. This works very well but it seems very wrong to be doing it this way. Also, it stops the application exiting properly because the thread isn't cancelled on Akka shutdown.

Is there a more accurate scheduler I can use for this task? Or is there a way of creating my own scheduler and plugging it in to Akka?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read up on #setDeamon on Thread, you can fix the exiting issue. And if this is just once or twice in your application, I would not worry about using a separate thread. That thread would probably be quite busy anyway.